# Run/Debug in Android studio on OSX in fullscreen mode always switch desktop

Tags: macos, desktop, fullscreen, android-studio

I am facing a rather frustrating behaviour when I'm running an android app or simple unit tests. I use Android Studio 1.3 in fullscreen mode on OSX 10.10.4 and every time I start the app or tests it switch back to the previous desktop.

Anyone know how to stop this? :)
Thanks